# how to disable or undo nnn Lock

Tags: terminal, file-manager

I've been using [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) for a few weeks now. Sometimes, being a `Vim` user, I've hit `L`, expecting to get me to the last visible line, but of course it's the command `Lock` in `nnn`. I can't figure out what it's doing. Both in `xterm` and in `urxvt` I get this endlessly repeating output:

```
The pts/25 is now locked by jo.
Authentication failure.
```

Then my only option is to kill the terminal. So how can I disable this command ('L'), or get out of this state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `vlock`.
Because you do not have an appropriate PAM configuration for `vlock` installed, it is falling back to the behaviour of immediately denying every authentication attempt.
Of course, `vlock` simply tries to authenticate over and over, in a loop, until successful.

The Clear Linux people had the same problem.

This is not an `nnn` problem.

## Further reading

- Matthew Johnson (2018-05-16). *[PAM authentication issues with `vlock` and `i3lock`](https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/66)*. Clear Linux Bug #66.

Comment: Correct. I see the process `vlock` appear, and my fix is, from another terminal, to `killall -9 vlock`, which brings back `nnn`.